# Webdriver: Why am i still getting 'Unexpected Alert Open'?

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have created the following method which click on a specific button which will open an alert, the same method listed below will then handle the alert.

But i seem to be getting the odd Jenkins build which will ***(intermittently)*** fail saying due to an unexpected alert open (Exception listed below), any ideas?

```
public void clickPaySecurelyNowButton() throws InterruptedException {
        waitAndclickElementUsingJS(button_PaySecurelyNowTop);

        WebDriverWait tempWait = new WebDriverWait(this.driver, 30);
        Alert alert = tempWait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
        boolean boolAlert = false;
        int attempts = 0;
        while (!boolAlert && attempts < 1000) {
            try {
                driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
                System.out.println("Successfully clicked on the 'Pay Securely Now Button' and 'Closed the popup'");
                boolAlert = true;
            } catch (org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException e) {
                driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
                boolAlert = true;
                System.out.println("Sucesffuly clicked on the 'Pay Securely Now Button' and 'Closed the popup'");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Unable to click on the 'Pay Securely Now Button', Exception: " + e.getMessage());
                Assert.fail("Method failed: clickPaySecurelyNowButton");
            }
        } attempts++;
    }
```

Exception flagged:

```
unexpected alert open
  (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 63 milliseconds: null
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'DEV007', ip: '172.16.2.192', os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233), userDataDir=C:\Users\GIANNI~1.BRU\AppData\Local\Temp\2\scoped_dir9140_30313}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=58.0.3029.110, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: 699ee1257882397cd7695aeaf919c68f
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//button[contains(text(), "Pay Securely Now")]}



org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: 
unexpected alert open
  (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 63 milliseconds: null
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'DEV007', ip: '172.16.2.192', os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233), userDataDir=C:\Users\GIANNI~1.BRU\AppData\Local\Temp\2\scoped_dir9140_30313}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=58.0.3029.110, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: 699ee1257882397cd7695aeaf919c68f
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//button[contains(text(), "Pay Securely Now")]}
    at BuyAGiftFramework.complete.AddingDrivingExperienceToBasketTest.clickOn_PaySecurelyNowButton(AddingDrivingExperienceToBasketTest.java:51)






TEST CLASS END TIME: 03.10.30
0
0
Tests run: 314, Failures: 80, Errors: 0, Skipped: 214, Time elapsed: 62.972 sec <<< FAILURE! - in TestSuite
clickOn_PaySecurelyNowButton(BuyAGiftFramework.complete.AddingDrivingExperienceToBasketTest)  Time elapsed: 0.298 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: 
unexpected alert open
  (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 63 milliseconds: null
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'DEV007', ip: '172.16.2.192', os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233), userDataDir=C:\Users\GIANNI~1.BRU\AppData\Local\Temp\2\scoped_dir9140_30313}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=58.0.3029.110, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: 699ee1257882397cd7695aeaf919c68f
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//button[contains(text(), "Pay Securely Now")]}
        at BuyAGiftFramework.complete.AddingDrivingExperienceToBasketTest.clickOn_PaySecurelyNowButton(AddingDrivingExperienceToBasketTest.java:51)

EmailFormatAndDataCapture(BuyAGiftFramework.complete.AddingDrivingExperienceToBasketTest)  Time elapsed: 0.299 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException: 
unexpected alert open: {Alert text : Click OK to confirm your personal message is correct as this is exactly how it will be printed.}
  (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 4 milliseconds: null
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'DEV007', ip: '172.16.2.192', os.name: 'Windows Server 2008 R2', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233), userDataDir=C:\Users\GIANNI~1.BRU\AppData\Local\Temp\2\scoped_dir9140_30313}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=58.0.3029.110, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true,
```

Comment: which line throws the erorr?

Comment: @kushal.im not sure, i have added the exception line(s) from jenkins

Comment: do you have any opened alerts after this error is received?

Answer (score 2):

In this line you're already taking the alert: `Alert alert = tempWait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());`

instead of writing `driver.switchTo().alert().accept();`, try doing it this way: `alert.accept();`

**UPDATE:**
If you just want to accept the alert at all costs, better move your try block outside the click line. I have a good reason to believe that the click line causes your unhandled alert exception as I have experienced the same problem before.

Try to update your code like so:

```
public void clickPaySecurelyNowButton() throws InterruptedException {

    try {
        waitAndclickElementUsingJS(button_PaySecurelyNowTop);

        WebDriverWait tempWait = new WebDriverWait(this.driver, 30);
        tempWait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
        boolean boolAlert = false;
        int attempts = 0;
        while (!boolAlert && attempts < 1000) {
            attempts++;
            driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
            System.out.println("Successfully clicked on the 'Pay Securely Now Button' and 'Closed the popup'");
            boolAlert = true;
        }
    } catch (org.openqa.selenium.UnhandledAlertException e) {
        driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
        boolAlert = true;
        System.out.println("Sucesffuly clicked on the 'Pay Securely Now Button' and 'Closed the popup'");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to click on the 'Pay Securely Now Button', Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        Assert.fail("Method failed: clickPaySecurelyNowButton");
    }
}
```

**==OR==**
You can use a global setting using chrome capabilities during driver instantiation:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.ACCEPT);

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: im afraid i have tried this already and im afraid the problem is still there

Comment: instead of running directly from jenkins, can you try to debug from your IDE and see which line is causing throwing the error? You need to check whether you're reaching the `try` block or the error is happening even before the `try` block itself. i had a similar problem before and I'm guessing that your error happens on this line: `waitAndclickElementUsingJS(button_PaySecurelyNowTop);` Please check and if it does, I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: the problem is its very difficult to replicate the issue, for example out of 200 builds one would cause the exception and therefore hard to replicate if im manually triggering the build every time :/

Comment: So this is an intermittent issue. I suggest you edit your question to state that this is an intermittent issue. You can either move the try block outside your click command or do a global driver setting to accept all unexpected alerts. See my updated answer.